# informatica power center On-premises & Azure SQLMI cloud database performance issue

Tags: sql-server, informatica

**informatica power center On-premises & Azure SQLMI cloud database  performance issue**

```
Earlier :
Database - sybase on-premises
informatica power center - on-premises
source - .txt file (1.8 million rows)
major transformation - Using 4 unconnected stored proc transformation (very simple logic nothing complex)
Target - flat file
```

Logic  - for every rows from source it calls stored proc and return the o/p.

it is calling stored proc for each source record means if source has 1.8 million records it will coll proc for 1.8 million time from power center to sqlmi database

Total time to run the job 18 million records - less than 2hr

```
Current scenario:  the only change we made is migrated our database to Azure SQLMI cloud database.
connection  - sql server ODBC (we also tried sql server relational conn)
```

and Total time it is taking to execute entire job is 24hr
performance has drastically reduces

has anyone faced this situation? what solution you have tried?

we tried changing connection from ODBC to
sql server relational connection

Comment: you're gonna get a lot of overhead if you send 18 mil requests over the wire. are you ure this is the best way to do things

Comment: This is a disastrous design. And no wonder it works bad, as now you make the 1.8 M calls over the internet, rather than locally, as you used to. But this was so bad even before and this should be reshaped. The design is the problem, not the performance, I'm afraid.